# How to access this attribute using jquery, given a div defined by this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which is defined via a this. Imagine it is the var div below:

```
<td itemid='desired number'>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div class="action">div 2</div>
</td>
```

Given the var div how can I work out the itemid attribute of the td which contains it. Note, I do not want a solution which directly accesses the itemid attribute, it has to the itemid which is containing div 2.

```
var div = $('.action')
```

I've tried using parent() with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: `.parent` should work just fine.. not sure why it is failing for you... Try `div.parent().attr('itemid')`

Comment: a note itemid is invalid html you can use data-* attributes , so if you write data-itemid will be valid html

Comment: Are you sure that your div is attached to the document ? You can check this with alert(div.parent().length). If it returns 0, it means that your div was not found by $(".action") because it's not attached to the dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var itemidValue = $('.action').parent('td').attr('itemid');
```

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/AwM56/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.parent()`, you can try using parents() and specify what you are looking for.

Example:

```
 $(".action").parents("td") // will return the TD element
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/9LQB3/

I use the parents() method instead of parent() as the parents() looks higher up the hierarchy, 
and not just the immediate parent.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use custom attributes, you should really be doing it with HTML5 `data-*` attributes, so use `data-itemid='desired number'` instead, then use the `.data()` rather than `.attr()` function to get the value.

HTML:

```
<td data-itemid='desired number'>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div class="action">div 2</div>
</td>
```

jQuery:

```
var div = $('.action');
var itemId = div.parent().data('itemid');
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `div.closest('td')`?

Answer (score 1):

`.parent()` should be OK.

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          var div = $('.action');
          console.log('HEP: ' + $(div).parent().attr('itemid'));
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td itemid='desired number'>
          <div>div 1</div>
          <div class="action">div 2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `var itemID = $('.action').parent().attr('itemid');`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried `parent`, but without an example that doesn't work, and with my inclination to assume it should work, may I suggest:

```
var val = div.parent().attr('itemid');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.action').parents('td').attr('itemid')`; should do it. BTW, that itemid attribute is invalid. Probably best to use the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try following jQuery statement:

```
$("TD[itemid='desired number']:has(.action)")
```