# How to get this attribute in a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access this attribute using jquery, given a div defined by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891960/how-to-access-this-attribute-using-jquery-given-a-div-defined-by-this)

I have included a simple jsfiddle to illustrate my difficulty:

http://jsfiddle.net/7HCyS/

I wish to access the `itemid` attribute of this:

```
<td itemid="1488324">
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:88px">
<div class="twitter-tweet" style="width:22px; height:22px;"></div>
<div class="facebook-post" style="width:22px; height:22px;"></div>
</div>
</td>​
```

I can't lookup itemid using jquery directly, I have to start with

```
 $('.facebook-post')
```

and go from there. I have been advised to use the parent method but it isn't helping me, any ideas?

Comment: How is this different from your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891960/how-to-access-this-attribute-using-jquery-given-a-div-defined-by-this?

Comment: Is there only one element with that class on the page?

Comment: none of the answers work that I can see...

Comment: @Hardworker: That doesn't mean you should post a new question.

Comment: The difference is that the first question had over-simplified html that didn't properly represent the real html.  `parent` "won't work" because your simplified html only had one level of nesting where as this real html has 2.

Comment: Then edit the question to explain your problem more clearly, and hence get better, more relevant, answers. Don't just keep repeating the same question, over again, in the hope that someone might get lucky.

Comment: Yes you are right james - that is another reason why I have asked again, I phrased my question poorly.. I didn't think the extra nesting would matter. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.facebook-post').closest('td').attr('itemid')
```

Comment: My jsfiddle doesnt show your code working?

Comment: That's because `<td>`s can't be outside of a table.  If it was in a table, it'd work.  http://jsfiddle.net/7HCyS/3/

Comment: You're right. I put a table around it and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle doesn't work because html is invalid having a `TD` without a `TR` or `table` for parents

working version  http://jsfiddle.net/7HCyS/1/

```
  $('.facebook-post').closest('td').attr('itemid')
```

Also `parent()` won't work because `TD` is not direct parent of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but the problem is your html in your JSFiddle isn't valid.  It's completely ignoring the td, because the td can only exist within a tr, which can only exist in a table <strike>I'm not 100% certain of that</strike>, but that's what I'm seeing in the console in Chrome.

Clarification: Browsers tend to do some strange things to correct for invalid html.  At first I was thinking browsers might incidentally wrap tds in tables, but, apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[itemid]")
```

seems to work if you enclose the `<td>` in a `<table>` and `<tr>` tag, which you should do.